# How to write a regex referencing the capture group in the replacement with a lookahead?

Tags: java

I would like to write a regex that matches either `fruit:foo` or `vegetable:baz`, and always replaces the first occurrence with `fruit:tomato` or `vegetable:tomato`. A single expression like `fruit:foo` can be matched with regex `fruit:[^, ]*`.

Input1: `{hello:world, fruit:apple, vegetable:broccoli] lorem ipsum`

Expected output1: `{hello:world, fruit:tomato, vegetable:broccoli] lorem ipsum`

Input2: `{hello:world, vegetable:broccoli, fruit:apple) dolor sit amet`

Expected output2: `{hello:world, vegetable:tomato, fruit:apple) dolor sit amet`

I think this will require referencing the capture group in the replacement as well as a lookahead, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replaceFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to replace the first occurrence of a string match with a different string. Since this method uses regex, you can use the regex `(fruit|vegetable):\w+` to look for anything that looks like `fruit:*` or `vegetable:*`. The replacement string can contain capture group names/indices to get either `fruit` or `vegetable`, depending on what was matched. See the [documentation of `Matcher.appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) on how to use `$x` in your replacement. The code can look like this:

```
String inputs[] = new String[] {
    "{hello:world, fruit:apple, vegetable:broccoli] lorem ipsum",
    "{hello:world, vegetable:broccoli, fruit:apple) dolor sit amet"
};
    
for (String input: inputs) {
    String result = input.replaceFirst("(fruit|vegetable):[^, ]*", "$1:tomato");
    System.out.println("Input was: "+input);
    System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
}
```

This will generate an output like this:

```
Input was: {hello:world, fruit:apple, vegetable:broccoli] lorem ipsum
Result is: {hello:world, fruit:tomato, vegetable:broccoli] lorem ipsum
Input was: {hello:world, vegetable:broccoli, fruit:apple) dolor sit amet
Result is: {hello:world, vegetable:tomato, fruit:apple) dolor sit amet
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I needed. However, the individual expressions need to match the regex `baz:[^, ]*`, so any character except for ` ` or `,` is allowed. You are only matching with word characters.

Comment: @ManakBisht I changed it to use the different regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String input1 = "{hello:world, fruit:apple, vegetable:broccoli} lorem ipsum";
    String input2 = "{hello:world, vegetable:broccoli, fruit:apple} dolor sit amet";

    String regex = "(fruit:|vegetable:)([^,}]+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(input1);
    if (matcher1.find()) {
        String replacement = matcher1.group(1) + "tomato";
        String output1 = matcher1.replaceFirst(replacement);
        System.out.println(output1);
    }


    Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(input2);
    if (matcher2.find()) {
        String replacement = matcher2.group(1) + "tomato";
        String output2 = matcher2.replaceFirst(replacement);
        System.out.println(output2);
    }
}
```